# Move to the next line when commenting a line in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just moved from PhpStorm to VS Code and there are still things I'm not used to.

When I comment a line with <kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd> the cursor stays in that line. I want my cursor to move to the next line (like it actually does in PhpStorm).

Any ideas on how I can add this "go to next line" action after commenting a line ?

Comment: I think you will have to use a macro extension to run two commands.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808372/836330 for more on `runCommands`. No extension is needed anymore as macro-like functionality has been built into vscode v1.77+ so these keybindings work now (in your `keybindings.json`):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+/",  // whatever keybindings you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.commentLine",
      "cursorDown"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+A",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.blockComment",
      "cursorDown"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

---

Previous Answer:

Using this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) and the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+/",                     // whatever you want 
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.commentLine",     // for line comments 
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter"
      // "cursorDown"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
  "key": "shift+alt+A",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.blockComment",       // for block comments too
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter"
      //  "cursorDown"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

The only downside to this is that it also inserts a line when you uncomment.  Instead of inserting a line, if you just want to go down a line (where there might be pre-existing text, use the command `"cursorDown"` instead.

Comment: Are there any additional steps? I copied that into my keybindings file and if I use `ctrl+/` the computer makes an error sound and if I change it to `cmd+/` then silently nothing happens, including no longer commenting out the line

Comment: @EricMajerus Didi you install the extension mentioned: Multi-command?

Comment: @Mark Ah stupid me... my noobness to VS Code misread that as "multi-command" being a term for a feature within VS Code and not a separate extension to install. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Though @Mark's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71225794/7744106) is helpful I found it incomplete for novice - I had to do extra research to implement the feature. So here are detailed steps.

1. Go to `View - Extensions`

[image]

2. Find and install `Multi-command` extension.

[image]

3. Go to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`. (`Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` on macOS)
4. `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` as on the screenshot below.

[image]

5. `keybindings.json` will be opened.

[image]

6. Add there the code @Mark published. My file now looks like this:

Windows/Linux:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+/",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
          "sequence": [
            "editor.action.commentLine",
            "cursorDown"
          ]
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
      }
]
```

MacOS:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+/",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
          "sequence": [
            "editor.action.commentLine",
            "cursorDown"
          ]
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
      }
]
```

7. Profit!

[image]

Comment: thanks, Microsoft doesn't know that this is actually a deal breaker, I suffer using vscode becoz of some of these little things. I love IntelliJ as some of these little things are baked in.

Answer (score 3):

As of today in Visual Studio Code 1.77.3, **you don't need the Multi-Command extension anymore**.

Furthermore, **the existing answers don't work well on wrapped lines**, where their behavior is to scroll the cursor to the next *screen* line, which is actually in the same "actual" line. (It's particularly problematic if you intend to also comment this next line with the same keybinding; the result is that you are *un*commenting the line you just commented.)

My proposal works without Multi-Command, and also fixes this annoyance. It overrides the ctrl + *numpad slash* key binding (change it as neeeded).

In your `keybindings.json`, add this block (for Windows/Linux):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+[NumpadDivide]",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        {
            "command": "editor.action.commentLine"
        },
        {
            "command": "cursorMove",
            "args": { "by": "line", "to": "down" }
        }
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

For macOS, replace "ctrl" by "cmd".

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions worked for me..almost lol
I'm on a mac and `"key": "cmd+/",` is better for me.
The solutions had `"key": "ctrl+/",`.  I'm guessing that's a windows thing.